# How to prevent a async task method get called concurrently

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, locking

I have a async task method which will be accessed on both foreground and background. In foreground, where user call this method via a button whereas in the background I have a timer triggering the method in some interval.

I tried put lock but it gives exception await can not be inside the lock statement.

```
    public static async Task<CommonResult<IEnumerable<AttendanceDTO>>> DownloadAttendanceAsync(string selectedDate, int siteId)
    {
        try
        { 
            if (new AttendanceBLL().IsLocalDataAvailable(siteId, DateTime.Parse(selectedDate)))
                return new CommonResult<IEnumerable<AttendanceDTO>>() { IsSuccess = true, Data = null };

            var queue = new EntityQueueBLL();
            //var latestUpdatedOn = queue.GetMaxUpdated(siteId, EntityIDEnum.Attendance);
            var url = string.Format(Constants.PathPullAttendance, selectedDate, siteId);
            var result = await new HttpRequestClient().GetRequest<IEnumerable<AttendanceDTO>>(url);

            if (!result.IsSuccess)
                return new CommonResult<IEnumerable<AttendanceDTO>>() { IsSuccess = false, Data = null, ErrorMessage = result.ErrorMessage };

            if (result.Data != null && result.Data.Count() > 0)
            {
                var maxUpdatedOn = result.Data.Max(x => DateTime.Parse(x.UpdatedOn));
                queue.Add(siteId, result.Data, result.Data.Count(), EntityIDEnum.Attendance, EntityType.Attendance, maxUpdatedOn);
            }

            return new CommonResult<IEnumerable<AttendanceDTO>> { IsSuccess = true, Data = result.Data }; 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new CommonResult<IEnumerable<AttendanceDTO>> { IsSuccess = false, Data = null, ErrorMessage = "Download Error" };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, what exactly do you want accomplish ? Do you want, in case of both events, to call method only once or do you want wait until first finishes and then call it again ?

Comment: if user call method, the background should not call until the the first finished.

Comment: And what if the timer fires a moment before user interaction? That would mean, that user method should wait right ? Or you want to interrupt background method and continue later ?

Comment: Yes to your former question. In case there is a chance both may enter the method at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried put lock but it gives exception await can not be inside the lock statement.

The `await`-compatible equivalent of `lock` is `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private static SempahoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
public static async Task<CommonResult<IEnumerable<AttendanceDTO>>> DownloadAttendanceAsync(string selectedDate, int siteId)
{
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  try
  { 
    ...
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return new CommonResult<IEnumerable<AttendanceDTO>> { IsSuccess = false, Data = null, ErrorMessage = "Download Error" };
  }
  finally
  {
    _mutex.Release();
  }
}
```

Comment: One question related to Xamarin iOS. if I have a background fetch who will calling this method as the same time while this method was executing. Will this create problem...

Comment: @LittleFunny: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with iOS background processes to say.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
AsyncLazy
```

For my initialization, which can be called from different threads. The task is only called once and other callers wait for it.

Answer (score -3):

try the below:

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
```